# Syntax error using os.system() Python

Tags: bash, python-3.x

I want to use the os.system command in order to get some information during a python script execution, but I get a syntax error, I'm literally using the same command on the terminal and the syntax it's correct.

the command is:

```
os.system(['df -h / | grep -E "\/$" | awk '{printf( $4)}''])
```

but the syntax error appears on the  **{**

thanks in advance.

Comment: You're inconsistent with your single vs double quotes. Stack overflow's syntax coloring should make this clear.

Comment: Try doing `os.system('df -h | grep -E "\/$" | awk \'{printf($4)}\'')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inconsistent with your single vs double quotes. Stack overflow's syntax coloring should make this clear.

You can fix your syntax error by escaping quotes as done by l'L'l, though I prefer wrapping the string in triple quotes. This avoids the need for escaped quotes (e.g. `\'`).

```
os.system(["""df -h / | grep -E "\/$" | awk '{printf( $4)}'"""])
```

Then you'll just have a `TypeError` because the function doesn't expect a list. Fix it like this:

```
os.system("""df -h / | grep -E "\/$" | awk '{printf( $4)}'""")
```

Comment: `os.system` should use a string though, not a list.